# Unable to resize a button using java.awt

Tags: java, awt

this is my code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Maapp extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    private int flag=0;
    Panel p1=new Panel();
    Panel p2=new Panel();
    Button[] arr=new Button[12];

    TextField textf=new TextField("",25);
    public void init()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.p2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,30));
        textf.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textf.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        this.p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,10));
        p2.add(textf);
        for(int i=0; i<10 ;i++)
        {

            arr[i]=new Button(""+i);
            arr[i].setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            arr[i].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            p1.add(arr[i]);
            this.arr[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
            arr[10]=new Button("=");
            p1.add(arr[10]);
            arr[10].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,40));
            this.arr[10].addActionListener(this);


        this.add(p2,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }





    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(arg0.getSource()==arr[i])
            {
                this.textf.setText(this.textf.getText()+i);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I want to resize one of the buttons.
I tried to write:

```
arr[10].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,40));
```

it did not work.
i tried to write:

```
arr[10].resize(10,20);
```

it did not work.

so how can i resize button `arr[10]`?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the min and max size of the button.  The layout manager you are using might not be able to honor the preferred size.

Comment: i am new at java... how can i min or max size of the button?

Comment: Use the API.  Look up the setMinimumSize method and how to use it.

Comment: I WRITE THAT CODE AND IT`S NOT WORKS..this.arr[10].setMaximumSize(getMaximumSize());

Comment: An API provides definitions for methods and classes.  The Core Java API can be found at: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: @asm_debugger: Dude, stop shouting!

Comment: I think you want to change the minimum size. Anyway, you want to define the size not just use the current size.  Lastly stop using all caps.

Comment: i what i need to do first to make change in 1 butten ?

Comment: i have a tutor in the uni.. but she send as to the internet becouse she want as to get alone....

Comment: I don't blame her, but the help you need is more than what a website can provide.

Answer (score 1):

For your button panel, you specified [`GridLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html), which ignores the preferred size. As an alternative, you can use [`GridBagLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) or [`MigLayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/), which can span columns.

Addendum: Note that you can indicate an arbitrary number of rows *or* columns in [`GridLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html). In your example, this would signify three columns with as many rows as required:

```
this.p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
```

Comment: I think that his arr[10] Button is added outside of the GridLayout and in a Panel that is then added via BorderLayout. If AWT is like Swing, then perhaps the Panel uses FlowLayout by default.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Thanks for looking at this closely, but I'm seeing `p1.add(arr[10])` and `p1` has `GridLayout`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't look at it as closely as you did. :(  Thanks for the correction!